# VS Code - Cannot Authorise Org when Cloned from Gitlab

Tags: vs-code

I cloned a repo from Gitlab which has all the necessary files for an SFDX project. However I don't get any options to authorise my org and instead VS Code is telling me to create a new project.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You opened the folder ENV as the workspace root folder. This means that SFDX will not detect this as a SFDX project. The root folder that is opened must be the folder that contains `sfdx-project.json`. Open the INTACT folder as the workspace root, and you'll have all your standard SFDX options.

Inside the GUI, you can use File > Open Folder... > select INTACT > Select Folder.

Or, you can go to the TERMINAL tab, and type in:

```
cd INTACT
code .
```